# Each open set is cofinite in a regular space implies the space is finite

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a regular ($T_{1}$) space such that for each non-empty open subset $U$ of $X$ the complement $X \setminus U$ is a finite set. Why this implies $X$ is finite?

Comment: @Asaf: I think $T_3$ *and* $T_1$ is meant. At some point in the past user10 made it clear that the main source of the questions is Dugundji's book, where regular means $T_3$, i.e., separating points from closed sets (without $T_1$). Btw. While regular can mean just about anything under the sun, I never heard it used for $T_1$. Also, if the cofinite topology (or a weaker one) is regular and $T_1$ then it is certainly Hausdorff, hence the space must be finite. I see no other interpretation than yours.

Comment: @Theo: I see. While I am certain that both versions of my answers are correct and useful to user10, I would rather wait for him to give a final clear for the interpretation so I could rest in peace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X=\{x\}$ then of course it is finite, otherwise there are $x_1,x_2\in X$ which are two distinct points.

Separate $x_1$ from $x_2$ by open sets $U_1$ and $U_2$ which are disjoint. Since $X\setminus U_1$ is finite, we have that $U_2$ is finite, $X\setminus U_2$ is also finite. Therefore $X=U_2\cup X\setminus U_2$ is the disjoint union of two finite sets and therefore finite.

Comment: geez! can't believe didn't see that, time to sleep, thank you!

Comment: @Asaf: Sorry, I deleted my confused comment.  I'm going to take a break.

Comment: @Jonas: It's fine, I was also confused about your comment. I'm not quite sure anymore if user10 means regular in the sense of separating points from closed sets, or just separating points, etc etc.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: regular and $T_{1}$, regular in the sense you can separate a point from a closed set. Thanks.

Comment: @user10: $T_1$ in the sense that distinct points can be separated, which also implies singletons are closed?